# VS2012 Multiple startup projects - Want command prompts to open on specific monitor

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, command, windows-console

I have a project which opens two command prompts as startup projects. My current environment has 3 monitors and I would like to open those command prompts on a secondary monitor (middle monitor is primary). Does anyone know of any way to do this in VS 2012 or any addons that can do this?

I've looked through Stackoverflow for similar questions but can't seem to find any that help. Please note that I cannot install other command line tools such as [CMDOW](http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/) or [Console2](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx). I want to get this working with the default console in Windows 7 Pro that comes up from Visual Studio 2012.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Note: this works with VS 2010 too.

Run your projects (Start Debugging in VS 2012). This will show up the two command prompts.

For each command prompt

- Position the command prompt on your secondary screen
- Open command prompt window > Properties > Layout
- In the "Windows Position" group box section, uncheck "Let system position window" (see attached image)
- Click OK and then close the command prompt

Next time you run your projects, your windows will be positioned to the location you set them to.

[image: Command Prompt Properties]

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me to set up the position for any CMD or batch file window in the middle of the two screens.